# Can I ensure that, when fopen()-ing a file for "w", the program doesn't create a file?

Tags: c

I'm writing a program that gathers user input for two file names, and opens one of them for reading and one of them for writing.
My code:

```
void 
gather_input (char* infileName, char* outfileName, char* mode,
          FILE* inputFile, FILE* outputFile)
{   int flag = 0; //error checking flag
do
{   flag = 0;
    printf("Enter the name of the source file: "); 
    scanf("%s", infileName);
    if (!(inputFile = open_input_file(infileName))) //will enter if statement only if
    {   fprintf(stderr, "Error opening '%s': %s\n", //inputFile == NULL
        infileName, strerror(errno)); //some error checking
        flag = 1; //true
    }
} while (flag);

do
{   flag = 0;
    printf ("Enter the name of the destination file: ");
    scanf("%s", outfileName);
    if (!(outputFile = open_output_file(outfileName)))
    {   fprintf (stderr, "Error opening '%s': %s\n",
        infileName, strerror(errno));
        flag = 1;
    }
} while (flag);
```

works fine on error-checking that the input file was opened; however, it fails to correct or detect that the output file was correctly entered or opened. This is part of a larger function, which I can post if needed (char* mode is used in a different section).

The problem is that when I say fopen(outfileName, "w"), which is what's happening in open_output_file(), the program will attempt to create a file if one doesn't exist (i.e., when the user gives garbage input). I want to avoid this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

man 3 fopen

```
``r+''  Open for reading and writing.  The stream is positioned at the
        beginning of the file.

``w''   Truncate file to zero length or create text file for writing.
        The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file.
```

So `"r+"` seems like a good candidate.

Answer (score 3):

Use open mode `"r+"` (reading and writing). 7.19.5.3/4 of the C99 standard:

> Opening a ﬁle with read mode ('r' as
>   the ﬁrst character in the mode
>   argument) fails if the ﬁle does not
>   exist or cannot be read.

This means you need read permission on the file, though.

Failing that if you're on POSIX you can use `open` to open the file, then `fdopen` to get a `FILE*` for the resulting file descriptor.